# не происходит обновление записи при выборе архива

Tags: php, sql

Данный код работает не правильно. При попытке отредактировать какой-либо архив(уже имеющийся в бд с остальными данными)  - вместо обновления имеющейся записи - создает новую. Подскажите пожалуйста , что нужно сделать чтобы заработало, как надо?

zanes.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'connect.php';
$id = $_POST['id'];
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
$user_id = $user['id'];
$user_id = (int)$user_id;
$title = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['title']);
$publicationtype = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['publicationtype']);
$author = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['author']);
$publisher = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['publisher']);
$compedit = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['compedit']);
$place = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['place']);
$year = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['year']);
$countpages = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['countpages']);
$archive = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['archive']);
$BBK = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['BBK']);
$UDK = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['UDK']);
$inventnumber = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['inventnumber']);
$numbinstances = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['numbinstances']);

if (isset($_FILES['file']['name']) && $_FILES['file']['name'] != '') {
   $file = $_FILES['file']['name'];
   $image_tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
   $image_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
   $image_ext = strtolower(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
   if ($image_size > 2 * 1024 * 1024) {
      echo "Error: File is too large";
      exit();
   }
   if ($image_ext != "jpg" && $image_ext != "jpeg" && $image_ext != "png") {
      echo "Error: Only JPG, JPEG or PNG are allowed";
      exit();
   }
   $image_name = uniqid() . '.' . $image_ext;
   $upload_dir = '../uploads/';
   $target_file = $upload_dir . $image_name;

   // Remove old file if exists
   $old_file_query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT file FROM infprintedit WHERE id = '$id'");
   $old_file = mysqli_fetch_assoc($old_file_query)['file'];
   if (!empty($old_file)) {
      $old_file_path = '../uploads/' . $old_file;
      if (file_exists($old_file_path)) {
         unlink($old_file_path);
      }
   }

   move_uploaded_file($image_tmp, $target_file);
} else {
   // If no new file was uploaded, keep the previous one
   $image_name = '';
}


// Проверка на значения в $archive
if ($archive == "ГКУ \"ЦГА УР\"" || $archive == "Филиал ГКУ \"ЦГА УР\"") {
   if (empty($id)) {
      // Если id не предоставлен, выполняем вставку новой записи
      $sql = "INSERT INTO infprintedit (file, title, publicationtype, author, year, publisher, compedit, place, countpages, user_id) VALUES ('$image_name', '$title', '$publicationtype', '$author', '$year', '$publisher', '$compedit', '$place', '$countpages', '$user_id')";
      $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

      $infprintedit_id = mysqli_insert_id($connect);

      $zapros = "INSERT INTO additional_info (infprintedit_id, archive, BBK, UDK, inventnumber, numbinstances) 
      VALUES ('$infprintedit_id', '$archive', '$BBK', '$UDK', '$inventnumber', '$numbinstances')";
      $result1 = mysqli_query($connect, $zapros);

      if (!$result || !$result1) {
         echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($connect);
         exit();
      }
   } else {
      // Если id предоставлен, выполняем обновление записи
      if (empty($image_name)) {
         // Если новый файл не выбран, сохраняем предыдущий файл
         $old_file_query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT file FROM infprintedit WHERE id = '$id'");
         $image_name = mysqli_fetch_assoc($old_file_query)['file'];
      }

      $sql = "UPDATE infprintedit SET
      file = '$image_name',
      title = '$title',
      publicationtype = '$publicationtype',
      author = '$author',
      year = '$year',
      place = '$place',
      publisher = '$publisher',
      compedit = '$compedit',
      countpages = '$countpages',
      user_id = '$user_id'
      WHERE id = '$id'";

      $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

      if (empty($image_name)) {
         // Удаляем имя файла из записи в базе данных 
         $sql = "UPDATE infprintedit SET file = NULL WHERE id = '$id'";
         $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
      }

      $zapros = "SELECT id FROM additional_info WHERE infprintedit_id = '$id' AND archive = '$archive'";
      $result1 = mysqli_query($connect, $zapros);

      if (mysqli_num_rows($result1) > 0) {
         // Если запись уже существует, выполнить обновление
         $zapros = "UPDATE additional_info SET BBK = '$BBK', UDK = '$UDK', inventnumber = '$inventnumber', numbinstances = '$numbinstances'WHERE infprintedit_id = '$id' AND archive = '$archive'";
         $result1 = mysqli_query($connect, $zapros);
      } else {
         // Если запись не существует, выполнить вставку новой записи
         $zapros = "INSERT INTO additional_info (infprintedit_id, archive, BBK, UDK, inventnumber, numbinstances) 
         VALUES ('$id', '$archive', '$BBK', '$UDK', '$inventnumber', '$numbinstances')";

         $result1 = mysqli_query($connect, $zapros);
      }

      // Добавьте следующую часть кода после обновления или вставки записи
      if (!$result1) {
         echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($connect);
         exit();
      }

      if (!$result || !$result1) {
         echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($connect);
         exit();
      }
   }
} else {
   // Если записывается другой архив, добавляем новую запись
   if (!empty($id)) {
      $infprintedit_id = $id;
      $zapros = "INSERT INTO additional_info (infprintedit_id, archive, BBK, UDK, inventnumber, numbinstances) 
      VALUES ('$infprintedit_id', '$archive', '$BBK', '$UDK', '$inventnumber', '$numbinstances')";
      $result1 = mysqli_query($connect, $zapros);

      if (!$result1) {
         echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($connect);
         exit();
      }
   }
}

header('Location: ../entry.php');
?>
```

entry.php

```
    ?>
    <form method="POST" action="vendor/zanes.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; flex-direction: column; align-items: center; text-align: center;">
            <div class="parent">
                <td>
                    <?php $image_src = empty($new_file_name) ? $row['file'] : $new_file_name; ?>
                    <img id="preview" margin="auto" onclick="openModal(this);" src="uploads/<?= $image_src ?>">
                    <br>
                    <input type="file" name="file" onchange="previewImage(this)">
                </td>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="label">
                <label>Название:</label>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="title" id="title">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id">
                    <div id="title_list" style="text-align: center; color: #00BB00; text-shadow: 1px 0 1px white,0 1px 1px white,-1px 0 1px white,0 -1px 1px white;"></div>
                </td>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="label">
                <label>Тип издания:</label>
                <select name="publicationtype">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="Однотомное издание">Однотомное издание</option>
                    <option value="Многотомное издание">Многотомное издание</option>
                    <option value="Собрание сочинений">Собрание сочинений</option>
                    <option value="Периодическое издание">Периодическое издание</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="label">
                <label>Авторы и составители:</label>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="author">
                </td>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="label">
                <label>Под редакцией:</label>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="compedit">
                </td>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="label">
                <label>Место:</label>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="place">
                </td>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="label">
                <label>Год:</label>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="year">
                </td>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="label">
                <label>Издательство:</label>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="publisher">
                </td>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="label">
                <label>Количество страниц:</label>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="countpages">
                </td>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="label">
                <label>Архив:</label>
                <td>
                    <select name="archive">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="ГКУ &quot;ЦГА УР&quot;">ГКУ &quot;ЦГА УР&quot;</option>
                        <option value="Филиал ГКУ ЦГА УР &quot;ГАОПИ&quot;">Филиал ГКУ ЦГА УР &quot;ГАОПИ&quot;</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="label">
                <label>ББК:</label>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="BBK" id="BBK">
                </td>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="label">
                <label>УДК:</label>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="UDK" id="UDK">
                </td>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="label">
                <label>Инвентарный №:</label>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="inventnumber">
                </td>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="label">
                <label>Количество экземпляров:</label>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="numbinstances">
                </td>
            </div>
            <br>
            <p>Последний изменивший запись:
                <span id="user_info">
                    <span id="familiya"></span>
                    <span id="imya"></span>
                    <span id="otchestvo"></span>
                </span>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div style="display:flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; align-items: center; margin-bottom: 50px; margin-top: 20px;">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <input type="submit" name="Save" value="Сохранить">
            </div>
        </form>
        <form action="mainpageoper.php">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <input type="submit" name="Back" value="Назад">
            </div>
        </form>
```

Дамп БД

```
CREATE TABLE `additional_info` (
  `id` int NOT NULL,
  `infprintedit_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `archive` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  `BBK` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  `UDK` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  `inventnumber` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  `numbinstances` int
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;


CREATE TABLE `infprintedit` (
  `id` int NOT NULL,
  `file` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  `title` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  `publicationtype` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  `author` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  `place` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  `year` int,
  `publisher` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  `compedit` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  `countpages` int,
  `user_id` int DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;


CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int NOT NULL,
  `familiya` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  `imya` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  `otchestvo` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  `login` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  `pass` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  `role` text
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

ALTER TABLE `additional_info`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `infprintedit_id` (`infprintedit_id`);

ALTER TABLE `infprintedit`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `FK_user_id` (`user_id`);

ALTER TABLE `users`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `additional_info`
  MODIFY `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=12;

ALTER TABLE `infprintedit`
  MODIFY `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=94;

ALTER TABLE `users`
  MODIFY `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=82;

ALTER TABLE `additional_info`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `additional_info_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`infprintedit_id`) REFERENCES `infprintedit` (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `infprintedit`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`);
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Обновение, это команда **update**, а **update** у вас выполняется, только если выполняется условие `if ($archive == "ГКУ \"ЦГА УР\"" || $archive == "Филиал ГКУ \"ЦГА УР\"")` и не выполняется условие `if (empty($id))` - Почему? Не приходит в пост запросе в `$_POST['id']` или `$_POST['archive']` или в `$_POST['archive']` значения, отличные от условия сравнения. Как понять, что не так? Нужны отладочные данные: Что уходит с клиента, что приходит и какие проверки проходят те или иные условные операторы